# How to switch power save mode between PS Poll and UAPSD (WMM) modes in CLI?

Tags: wifi, power-management, qos, iwlwifi

I'm trying to figure out if there are any chances to switch on/off U-APSD power save mode at my laptop. Currently I found a command to switch power save mode on/off:

```
root@host # iw dev wlan3 set power_save on/off
```

I suppose it just switches power save on/off without consideration of PSPoll/UAPSD power saving mode. So, I guess if AP supports UAPSD it will be used. But I need UAPSD (WMM) to be off.

Also I saw a WMM is availabe for my card:

```
root@host # iw dev wlan3 station dump
Station 00:e1:6d:XX:XX:XX (on wlan3)
    inactive time:  148 ms
    rx bytes:       5983752
    rx packets:     27939
    tx bytes:       1075591
    tx packets:     8168
    tx retries:     632
    tx failed:      0
    signal:         -58 dBm
    signal avg:     -56 dBm
    tx bitrate:     130.0 MBit/s MCS 15
    authorized:     yes
    authenticated:  yes
    preamble:       long
    WMM/WME:        yes
    MFP:            no
    TDLS peer:      no
```

So is there any possibility to switch WMM on/off?

WiFi module: `Intel 7260`

Answer (score 0):

From modinfo iwlwifi:

```
parm:           uapsd_disable:disable U-APSD functionality (default: Y) (bool)
```

it looks like it's disabled by default.